# passing testRunner object in class in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to execute the below groovy code in a soapUI groovy script test step. I am new to groovy and not sure if this the right way to pass object in a class. If I dont put my code in `RunTestSteps` class and `runSteps` method , it works fine.
Below, I am trying to pass `testRunner` object in `RunTestSteps` class. Groovy script test step by default is invoked with `testRunner` object.

```
class RunTestSteps{


def testRunner;
    RunTestSteps(testRunner)
    {
        this.testRunner=testRunner;
        }


def runSteps = {
   def TC= testRunner.testCase
   def TestStepCollection= testRunner.testCase.getChildren()
   //log.info(TestSptepCollection.size())
for (int i = 1; i < TestStepCollection.size() ; i++) 
{
    do something ..

   }

else {

do something else
    }
}
}

}


def run = new RunTestSteps().runSteps
 run()
```

I get this error upon running.

```
ERROR:An error occurred [Cannot get property 'testCase' on null object], see error log for details
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Groovy scripting, the rules are:

1. There are **no** class declarations.
2. There are **no** method declarations.

Read all about it in the documentation [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scripts+and+Classes) and [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java).

Your code will reduce to:

```
def testStepCollection = testRunner.testCase.getChildren()
testStepCollection.each {
    // do something, refering to each item as 'it'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I put  `def run = new RunTestSteps().runSteps; run()` in groovy script test step and put the class in diff file and have soapUI read that class file from preferences. The code is now running.